# tracd server problems

Tags: trac, tracd

I got the following error while accessing tracd server, what's going on ?

Thanks.

```
[oke@localhost Trac-0.11.7]$ sudo tracd -p 8000 /home/deddihp/trac/
Server starting in PID 5082.
Serving on 0.0.0.0:8000 view at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 47804)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 558, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 320, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 615, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 329, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Trac-0.11.7-py2.6.egg/trac/web/wsgi.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    gateway.run(self.server.application)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Trac-0.11.7-py2.6.egg/trac/web/wsgi.py", line 94, in run
    response = application(self.environ, self._start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Trac-0.11.7-py2.6.egg/trac/web/standalone.py", line 100, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Trac-0.11.7-py2.6.egg/trac/web/main.py", line 346, in dispatch_request
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, environ['trac.locale'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/locale.py", line 513, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
Error: unsupported locale setting
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to install the missing locale(s). Check with command "locale" to see what environment variables cannot be set.

```
[calvin@hobbes:~]$ locale
    locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
        locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
        locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
        LANG=en_US.UTF-8
        LANGUAGE=en_US:en
        LC_CTYPE="en_US"
        LC_NUMERIC="en_US"
        LC_TIME="en_US"
        LC_COLLATE="en_US"
        LC_MONETARY="en_US"
        LC_MESSAGES="en_US"
        LC_PAPER="en_US"
        LC_NAME="en_US"
        LC_ADDRESS="en_US"
        LC_TELEPHONE="en_US"
        LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US"
        LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US"
        LC_ALL=en_US
```

Then use command "locale-gen" to install the missing "en_US" locale:

```
[calvin@hobbes:~]$ sudo locale-gen en_US
    Generating locales (this might take a while)...
      en_US.UTF-8... done
    Generation complete.
```

Finally, use command "dpkg-reconfigure" to reconfigure all available locales:

```
[calvin@hobbes:~]$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
    perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
    perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
            LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
            LC_ALL = "en_US",
            LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
        are supported and installed on your system.
    perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
    locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
    locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
    locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
    /usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
    /usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
    /usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
    Generating locales (this might take a while)...
      en_GB.ISO-8859-1... done
      en_GB.ISO-8859-15... done
      en_GB.UTF-8... done
      en_US.ISO-8859-1... done
      en_US.ISO-8859-15... done
      en_US.UTF-8... done
      pt_PT.ISO-8859-1... done
      pt_PT.UTF-8... done
      pt_PT.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
    Generation complete.
```

Then you can see no more errors on the "locale" command output:

```
[calvin@hobbes:~]$ locale
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    LANGUAGE=en_US:en
    LC_CTYPE="en_US"
    LC_NUMERIC="en_US"
    LC_TIME="en_US"
    LC_COLLATE="en_US"
    LC_MONETARY="en_US"
    LC_MESSAGES="en_US"
    LC_PAPER="en_US"
    LC_NAME="en_US"
    LC_ADDRESS="en_US"
    LC_TELEPHONE="en_US"
    LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US"
    LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US"
    LC_ALL=en_US
```

Restart your tracd server and you should be fine.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you try to run tracd with unsupported locale, try to set it to your desired locale (en_US?) before starting trac daemon.

```
LC_ALL=en_US sudo tracd -p 8000 /home/deddihp/trac/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after uninstalling Apache2 (I wanted to use Trac's standalone server). I solved the problem by simply reinstalling the language pack:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall language-pack-en
```

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue with "Error: unsupported locale setting"
with some trac(s) i did not use for some time.
solved by setting locales, updating to latest version

basically:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

or set manually as Miguel Rentes wrote in his answer earlyer. In my case de_DE.UTF8

then updated easyinstall and trac with these commands:

```
wget http://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python
```

got: "certificate error"

```
wget --no-check-certificate http://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python
```

then

```
easy_install http://svn.edgewall.org/repos/trac/branches/0.12-stable
```

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS same issue for me was solved by comparing

`/etc/sysconfig/i18n` to valid installed locales identified by `locale -a`

I edited `/etc/sysconfig/i18n` and changed `UTF-8` to `utf8`, as this was a valid locale.

All symptoms then vanished.